# Assistance On CRUD Operations For Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

---

I don't have much experience and I'm trying to create a simple note taking application where I can use CRUD. I've gotten as far as being able to create a note but I'm stuck on what to actually put for Delete/Put.

Code Below

---

***My app.js file:***

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const methodOverride = require("method-override")

const app = express();
const Note = require('./models/note');
const notesRouter = require('./routes/notes');
require('dotenv').config();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const notes = await Note.find().sort('-createdAt');
  res.render('index', { notes: notes });
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notes', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use('/', notesRouter);
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`Server Has Started`);
});
```

***My notes.js file:***

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Note = require('../models/note');

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('new');
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let note = await new Note({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
  });
  try {
    note = await note.save();
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.render('new');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

I can't seem to find the correct code to put in so that I can actually delete or update an existing note.
I would appreciate any information and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete operation -

```
router.route('/delete/:id')
.delete((req, res)=>{
const {id}=req.params;
Note.findOneAndDelete({_id:id})
.then(()=>res.send('deleted!'))
.catch(err=>res.send(err))
})
```

Set your own route if required, from frontend send `id` or something else by which you can find the document in the database, and use/replace accordingly to complete the operation.

For update a note- use `put`

```
router.route('/update/:id')
.put((req, res)=>{
const {id}=req.params;
const {updateField1, updateField2, updateField3}=req.body;
Note.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id}, {$set:{updateField1, updateField2, updateField3}})
.then(()=>res.send('Note updated!'))
.catch(err=>res.send(err))

})
```

Comment: This was more than helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: @Vibras, if you find this answer works for you, please set/mark it as your solution by pressing the tick mark from the left where the answer starts, and also put an upvote